# call remote webservice using json

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services

I made a webservice for me it's works fine in local computer.

Now i deploy my project on iis and want to use that service from service deployed url

service works fine on that url

but when i use that url in json not working. Here is my code it works fine

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "WebService.asmx/getlinqdata",
        data: '{}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (jsonText) {

            var myObject = eval(jsonText.d);

            for (var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
                $('#main').append('<p>' + myObject[i].Id + '</p>');
                $('#main').append('<p>' + myObject[i].Name + '</p>');
                $('#main').append('<p>' + myObject[i].Day + '</p>');
                $('#main').append('<p>' + myObject[i].Month + '</p>');
                $('#main').append('<p>' + myObject[i].Year + '</p>');
                $('#main').append('<br/>');
            }


        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert("Error: " + msg.d);
        }
    });
```

this works fine for me but when i use deployed webservice url this url is
http://localhost:1234/WebService.asmx/getlinqdata

getlinqdata is my function to call

thax

Comment: Do you need the full url? Like: url: "localhost:1234/WebService.asmx/getlinqdata",

Comment: Does your IIS app pool have access to your database?  Like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951684/asp-net-mvc2-getjson-jquery-windows-7-64bit-iis

Comment: Ya using that url i am able to see all return xml data from data base
but when i use that url this json script display error

Comment: @VbPatel: what error exactly do you see?

Comment: I show error undefined....Just giv me other code using that we can get data from live web service url using json

Comment: Hey is there a problem of cross domain i host my service on 1234 and i want to use it on 3456.So this is my problem?????

Comment: @VbPatel: Post your web service method. There's nothing wrong with the piece of code you showed. By the way, you are using JQuery to call a web service via Ajax; there's no such thing as calling a web service using a `JSON script`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely go from one domain (URL) to another (that is cross domain), you cannot use JSON as it is, but instead have to rely on JSONP.

you will check out below references. Hopes its work for u

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Cross_Domain_Call.aspx

http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/SharePoint-Online-and-External-Data-using-JSONP.aspx

Comment: thx jig i found my problem it's cross domain problem i use codeproject link and it's work like charm thx man

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer based on your comments:

1234 is a **port number** not a domain. If you know that your issue is that locally you test your website on port 1234 (as opposed to 80) and on the production server you run it on port 3456, why don't you just change the Web Service URL to the appropriate port when you deploy to production?

One more suggestion:

[Eval is evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx). Don't use it when you have a better approach [like parseJSON.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

```
var myObject = $.parseJSON(jsonText.d);
```

Comment: i search a lot and found that issue.It is when we get data from cross domain then jsonp is used. any idea on that....